# cocos2d ccDrawPoly crash

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, drawing

I'm trying to use ccDrawPoly to create some random looking asteroid-like polygons. To do this, I've written a simple function that draws a circle in segments (randomizing the circles radius over each iteration) to create a sort of 'bumpy' polygon. The vertices are stored in an NSMutableArray and then fed to ccDrawPolygon (code below):

```
float maxRadiusVariation = self.radius * 0.2; // 20% of radius
float cx = self.radius, cy = self.radius;
int minSegmentAngle = 5;
int maxSegmentAngle = 45;
int angle = 0;

while(angle < 360)
{
    float newRadius = self.radius/2 + rand()%(int)maxRadiusVariation;

    float x = cx + (cos(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * newRadius);
    float y = cy + (sin(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * newRadius);

    [vertices addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y], nil]];

    int angleIncrement = minSegmentAngle + rand()%maxSegmentAngle;
    angle += angleIncrement;
}
```

cocos2d is crashing internally on a call to draw. I believe my problem may be in how I'm grabbing the polygon vertices out of my NSMutableArray cache and attempting to plot them:

```
CGPoint cgVertices[[vertices count]];

    for(int i = 0; i < [vertices count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *vertex = [vertices objectAtIndex:i];
        float x = [[vertex objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
        float y = [[vertex objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        cgVertices[i] = ccp(x, y);
    }
    ccDrawPoly(cgVertices, [vertices count], YES);
```

For a bit of further information, I've included an example of the vertices array contents before cocos2d crashes. To make it a little easier to visualise, I've included a graphic I created (where the blue pixel represents the circles centre, the white pixels are vertexes and the red lines are the lines connecting them).

http://nial.me/output.png

```
(
        (
        93,
        60
    ),
        (
        "96.25231",
        "76.90473"
    ),
        (
        "91.17692",
        78
    ),
        (
        "83.78063",
        "81.41218"
    ),
        (
        "78.77886",
        "95.3179"
    ),
        (
        "68.77309",
        "98.00043"
    ),
        (
        44,
        "87.71281"
    ),
        (
        "34.08406",
        "87.79144"
    ),
        (
        "26.45318",
        "81.78556"
    ),
        (
        "22.51079",
        "70.74986"
    ),
        (
        "23.02254",
        "61.29128"
    ),
        (
        "27.64341",
        "44.21864"
    ),
        (
        "30.8436",
        "37.22053"
    ),
        (
        "52.57661",
        "27.84579"
    ),
        (
        "62.44148",
        "25.08526"
    ),
        (
        "73.42231",
        "29.853"
    ),
        (
        "84.13467",
        "37.49406"
    ),
        (
        "89.13047",
        "49.39737"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you drawing outside the draw method? If you are, the following explanation might help.

You cannot use ccDrawPoly outside the CCNode draw function.
Notice it states in caps ***'DON'T draw your stuff outside this method'***. In the following definition of CCNode's draw method.

`// This is CCNode's draw method`

```
-(void) draw
{
        // override me
        // Only use this function to draw your stuff.
        // DON'T draw your stuff outside this method
}
```

Example of ccDrawPoly in cocos2d-ios: ActionsTest.m

```
-(void) draw
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    float x = winSize.width*2 - 100;
    float y = winSize.height;

    CGPoint vertices[] = { ccp(5,5), ccp(x-5,5), ccp(x-5,y-5), ccp(5,y-5) };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices, 4, YES);
}
```

Source:[Draw and Update Reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3adraw_update?s%5B%5D=draw)